# How to set the position of spinner with cordova

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have this in my config.xml

```
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
```

And the spinner works great, however i need to change the position from `center` to something like `center + 10%` vertically

There is any way of doing this?

Comment: you will have to edit the source code of the splash screen plugin

Comment: @Akis I am using phonegap builder. Can you explain how to make that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to fork the original [cordova-plugin-splashscreen on github](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen)

Then on your config.xml you change it to use your fork, remove the original plugin (something like `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" />`) and add your fork `<plugin spec="https://github.com/youruser/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git" />`

You have to change this lines to do what you want
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/blob/master/src/android/SplashScreen.java#L355-L370

Right now it centers the dialog, I'm not really sure how to accomplish what you want, you'll have to figure out how Android layouts work

You can try to use setY as progressBar is a View subclass, something like this:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
float position = (float) (height*0.4);
progressBar.setY(position);
```

Comment: Another option is to edit the spinner itself. I believe that is the correct solution, as I see no 'offset' or another way of repositioning a 'child view': 
So to speak, add some padding to the spinner?